# Minimum in Calculus

Tags: calculus, optimization

An advertising billboard will cost \$1 per square meter of surface, plus \$10 per linear meter of base width. Given that the cost of a billboard was \$400, what is the minimum possible perimeter of that billboard? Justify that your answer really represents the minimum.

I tried making this function

$x^2+10x=400$

Is this statement correct ?

Comment: How did you get to that step?

Comment: I made it, I think I can derivate it, but I am confused

Comment: It's not as straightforward as you think. Can you write an equation using the base ($b$) and height ($h$). Then you can isolate one of the variables which will give you an expression for the perimeter.

Comment: Could you give an initial statement please?

Comment: is it a rectangle or a cuadrangle?

Comment: Should be a rectangle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112098/discussion-between-toby-mak-and-rosita-galixx).

Answer (score 2):

Let $b$ be the base, and $h$ be the height. Then:

$$bh \cdot 1 + b \cdot 10  =400$$
$$b(h + 10) = 400$$

Thus $b = \frac{400}{h + 10}$. Since the perimeter can be written as $2(b + h)$, you now have to minimise:

$$2 \left(\frac{400}{h+10} + h \right).$$

Comment: is the final answer 20?

Comment: $h  = 20$, but the perimeter is larger.